# SQL Server SCD II implementation quandary

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, scd

I have a patient table with north of 80 fields, of which I'll need to keep historical data on all fields. For clarification, not all fields "need" versioning, though the decision was made to simply keep a full copy of the old records.

For clarification, this is for an ETL process, which will be taking place off-hours.

There seem to be a few approaches here, though I don't know which one will work best for me, as I haven't done this before.

**Option 1**: use SSIS for an SCD implementation.
  Pro: Since we're using SSIS anyhow to source our data, it would make sense to simply continue using the same tool
  Con: I've read some articles on the performance of SCD in SSIS - example: https://chrisjarrintaylor.co.uk/2012/07/03/ssis-scd-vs-merge-statement-performance-comparison/

**Option 2**: Use `MERGE` in a tsql statement.
  Pro: short to write, simple to understand - does all steps in one
  Con: can be cumbersome if we try to write conditions on 80+ fields. We may also have a performance issue doing an `OR` on that many fields (as in, if any are different)
The following approach would work for me, though writing it that way, would mean a very long merge statement: [Need help understanding alternatives to scd in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40665273/need-help-understanding-alternatives-to-scd-in-ssis)

**Option 3**: `INSERT` all of the new records, use a CTE to clean up duplicates (those that have no change), an `UPDATE` statement to deactivate those records which changed
  Pro: No messy `OR` statements, not too hard to write or understand - performance doesn't seem as if it'll be an issue (we've used the CTE approach in the past)
  Con: Somehow, this comes across as being highly kludgy approach

Considering these approaches, or others which you may have, is there one which is easier to maintain, will scale better?

Small sampling of data - there are 80+ columns in source data (which I cannot control) and much more rows: http://rextester.com/live/AYQUT28070

Comment: Are you talking about a Type 1 SCD or a Type 2? The title implies Type 2 but the options you're describing, MERGE in particular sounds better suited to Type 1... Are you trying to update existing data that's changed (type 1) or are you trying to maintain a change history of changed data (type 2)?

Comment: 80+ fields is a sure sign of bad normalization (or simply lack of normalization). Any operation in a relational database with bad normalization will always be awkward and/or have bad performance.

Comment: If you don't get any good answer here, you might try asking this at the [SE Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) sister site (but refrain from cross posting).

Comment: @JasonA.Long SCD 2. I want to import a record into a staging table. If there are any changes, I'll need to deactivate the previous record and use the new one, otherwise, I need to ignore this new row

Comment: @TT. it is a vendor system, and I, unfortunately, don't have any control over the data structure. We're getting data dumps and I'm trying to make the best of the situation. I'll take a peek at the SE stack as well, thanks for letting me know about it

Comment: @JasonA.Long I'm referring to SCD II. As for sounding like a SCD I, I understand where you got that idea. As for the Merge, I would have a nested Merge which would accomplish two things - mark current record as inactive, insert a new record.

Comment: I'll state this a personal preference simply because there are several legitimate ways to model this... My personal preference is to use the "type 6 model"... The main table kept as a type type 1, having only the most current information and then use separate type 2 or "history " tables to hold the history of handful of columns that need versioning.

Comment: @JasonA.Long interesting. I read up about this model on Kimbal, and it doesn't use a second table. I have heard of others who use your described method, though I don't want to go the path of triggers (that was how they "moved" data to the historical table

Comment: A mistake on my part... I should have said "type 4" not 6... The difference being that, the history tale only includes those columns that need a type 2 history. So, if you only need history for 6 of the 80 columns, the history table would contain only thise columns plus a the ID to join back to the main table and the change datetime.

Comment: Understood. It seems as if you have done this in the past, with that assumption, how have you managed the moving parts of the data?